# Unable to delete document from firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in my javascript file, it seems to run fine but when I look at the firestore console, the document is still there. And if I run my init code that downloads from firestore, it loads the doc into my app. The database rules allow all access so don't see a problem deleting the document there. In fact, elsewhere I have similar code and it successfully deletes documents from firestore. Scratching my head, this code should delete the document from firestore but it just won't. I have Googled this problem all day and can find no explanation or similar issue. I have tried deleting and recreating my entire database, deleted and created new users. But the category documents in the 'categories' collection just won't delete from code (from console yes)

HERE IS MY CODE

```
deleteCategory({ commit }) {
    // save id before we delete from vuex so we can delete from firestore after
    let id_to_delete = state.categories[state.currentCategory].id
    console.log('idToDelete BEFORE = ', id_to_delete)
    console.log('cat id in vuex', state.categories[state.currentCategory].id)
    
    commit('deleteCategory')

    // now go out to database and delete this category
    console.log('HOOK: delete category from cloud here')
    console.log('user id=', state.userID)
    console.log('idToDelete AFTER = ', id_to_delete)
    let catRef = fs.collection('users')
      .doc('state.userID')
      .collection('categories')
      .doc(id_to_delete)
    
    console.log('catRef=', catRef)
    
    catRef.delete().then(function() {
        console.log('Category successfully deleted!')
        console.log('THEN: user id=', state.userID)
        console.log('THEN: idToDelete = ', id_to_delete)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Error removing category: ', error)
      })
  },
```

HERE IS MY CONSOLE OUTPUT:

idToDelete BEFORE =  b6f58a4e-6aa4-4e8a-9925-c3f7948739dc

cat id in vuex b6f58a4e-6aa4-4e8a-9925-c3f7948739dc

HOOK: delete category from cloud here

user id= JFRImEwHsNMidmUqxhS80lXioDs1

idToDelete AFTER =  b6f58a4e-6aa4-4e8a-9925-c3f7948739dc

catRef= t {$c: t, firestore: t, hE: undefined, WT: t}

Category successfully deleted!

THEN: user id= JFRImEwHsNMidmUqxhS80lXioDs1

THEN: idToDelete =  b6f58a4e-6aa4-4e8a-9925-c3f7948739dc

HERE ARE MY DATABASE RULES:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 6, 24);
    }
  }
}
```

HERE IS WHAT FIRESTORE LOOKS LIKE AFTER RUNNING CODE:

LEFT PANE:

categories

MIDDLE PANE:

categories

4f0e7a78-7787-41df-bea5-66a01f41a7c8

b6f58a4e-6aa4-4e8a-9925-c3f7948739dc

RIGHT PANE:

b6f58a4e-6aa4-4e8a-9925-c3f7948739dc

descriptions

ids

name: "people"

things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug, I was passing a string literal as userID instead of var, dumb error. Didn't find it until firestore finally gave me an error message, don't know why not getting error message before.